# How to create an event-triggered alarm signal in HTML which lasts a fixed amount of time (say 1 hour)?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am developing a web application to create an event-triggered alarm signal.

1. Trigger event

   The trigger event is any changes in my schedule table database. That is, whenever there is a change in my schedule table, it triggers the alarm signal
2. Alarm signal

   The alarm signal could be a red flashing icon which lasts for 1 hour. If there is no new change, the alarm signal should go off.

Please note that the browser could be closed. But I want to make sure next time when I open this application in the browser and if I am still within the 1 hour window of a schedule change, my web application should automatically catch this and turn on the alarm for a duration left in the 1 hour window.

Currently I got stuck on how I can make the alarm to last 1 hour? How can my program detect the changes even after the browser is closed and re-opened again?

P.S. I am using JSP on the back-end on Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply query the database for any alarms that went off in the past hour.

If you acknowledge an alarm while it's up, though, you'll want to make sure to send that ack to the database so when you open it up later (assuming you're still in the hour) that you only grab alarms that haven't been acked.

That's your basic algorithm. If you wanted specifics, you'd have to post a question with code.